# Is it better to use multiple workers that perform the same task for inputs or one worker that performs the task multiple times for inputs?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

Is it better to use multiple workers that perform the same task for inputs or one worker that performs the task multiple times for inputs?

1 worker :

```
\\\ SomeWorker.class
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Worker.Result doWork() {
        Context applicationContext = getApplicationContext();
        boolean success = Boolean.TRUE;
        List<String> resourceUris = new ArrayList<String>(has a list of strings);

        for (String resourceUri : resourceUris) {
            success = doSomething(resourceUri);
        }

        return success ? Result.success() : Result.retry();
    }

\\\ Viewmodel.class

OneTimeWorkRequest save = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(SomeWorker.class)
                .addTag(TAG_OUTPUT)
                .build();
workManager.beginUniqueWork(save).enqueue();
```

Vs

Multiple workers which do one task independently :

```
\\\ Someworker.class
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Worker.Result doWork() {
        Context applicationContext = getApplicationContext();
        String resourceUri = getInputData().getString("RESOURCE_URI");
        return doSomething(resourceUri) ? Result.success() : Result.retry();
    }


\\\ Viewmodel.class

List<String> resourceUris = new ArrayList<String>(has a list of strings);
List<OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder> someBuilder;
for (int i = 0; i < resourceUris.size(); i++) {
           someBuilder.add( new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(Someworker.class));
}

workManager.beginUniqueWork(someBuilder).enqueue();
```

It seems like the first approach will consume less memory but will take longer vs the second which will consume more memory due to more work managers but will take shorter time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

I would say use one `Worker` unless you know you might run over the `10` minute execution window, or if you know there are parts of the `Worker` that are useful independently (i.e. reusable from other parts of the app).

Comment: But can you distributed the task within one worker to run in parallel or would you have to spin up multiple ones to achieve that.

Comment: You can also distribute a task to run in parallel with multiple threads or coroutines. Every WorkRequest has a cost (persistence + scheduling). You should try and avoid that cost when you can.